# Prove the following $A \setminus (A \cap B) = A \setminus B$, for $B \subseteq A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help to prove:

> $A \setminus (A \cap B) = A \setminus B$, for $B \subseteq A$.

Thanks

Comment: First thing, is that supposed to say $B\subseteq A$? Secondly, what have you tried?

Comment: Please learn some basic MathJax to typeset your mathematics.  Here's a tutorial:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 7):

If $B\subseteq A$ what is $A \cap B$?

Comment: ohh thanks, sorry I just begin to learn it :)

Answer (score 3):

First draw a Venn diagram, then try make it a vigorous proof.

Comment: Doesn't it supposed to be rigorous?

Comment: @GinKin he probably meant rigorous, but you could also write a proof vigorously after you have seen a Venn diagram!

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what elements are in the most complex set expression in this problem, viz. $\;A \setminus (A \cap B)\;$: for all $\;x\;$
\begin{align}
& x \in A \setminus (A \cap B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot(x \in A \cap B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot(x \in A \land x \in B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: use left conjunct $\;x\in A\;$ in right part; simplify"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot(x \in B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$"} \\
& x \in A \setminus B \\
\end{align}

So by set extensionality, $\;A \setminus (A \cap B) = A \setminus B\;$.

Note that we did not need to use the condition $\;B \subseteq A\;$: the statement is true for *all* $\;A,B\;$.

Answer (score 1):

You could element chase but it would be easiest to consider what $B\subseteq A$ means about $A
\cap B$.  Then, you could prove that statement and then this would be way easier.

Answer (score 1):

And a pure formal proof:
$$A\setminus (A\cap B)=A\cap(\neg(A∩B))=A∩(\neg A\cup\neg B)=\varnothing \cup A\cap\neg B=A\setminus B$$